# Regular expression in Unix using or operator

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I'm trying to print,using grep, lines which contains `vasile` or line which contains `ion` . This is command but it doesn't work:

```
grep (vasile|ion) test.txt
```

I don't need this :

```
grep vasile test.txt | grep ion test.txt
```

Comment: If you want to use regular expressions in `grep` you should really switch to `egrep` or something like `grep -P` (perl style regex) depending on which style you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try,

```
terminal$ grep -e vasile -e ion test.txt
```

Other way using OR operator `|` in grep

```
terminal$ grep 'vasile\|ion' test.txt
```

Comment: You can use "|" operator also, see updated answer, but you need to escape it before using otherwise it will consider as a normal | character in pattern

Comment: wait 1 minute more :D, if i want to find 'vasile" "\|ion' how can i do?  using "|" operator.

Comment: means do you want to match `" "` in pattern??

Comment: i want find vasile followed by space, but i found one solution 'vasile[" "]\|ion'

Comment: simple, you can just leave one blank space after vasile like `grep 'vasile \|ion' test.txt`

Comment: ups,so embarrassing :))

Comment: hahaha.. have a look at beginners guide. It will help you. :) http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use `awk`, you can do:

```
awk '/vasile|ion/' test.txt
```

```
awk '/vasile/ || /ion/' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try alternation with Grep's extended regex option:

```
grep -E 'vasile |ion' file
```

This should work with all Posix greps. `\|` is a GNU extension to BRE..